# submit button is not working. i have a mysql database and i am trying to make a php form

Tags: php, html, mysql

when i hit the submit button, nothing happens. perhaps the database is not connected. i am trying to make a form using php and html. i am using xampp, i wrote the code in notepad++ and i saved form.php in htdocs. i don't know what is wrong. maybe the names i used for the variables.

this is the html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="C:\xampp\htdocs\form.php">
    Nume de utilizator : <input type="text" name="nume_de_utilizator" placeholder="Enter Your Name" >
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
    Parola: <input type="password" name="parola">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

this is form.php

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "autentificare";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$nume_de_utilizator = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nume_de_utilizator']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$parola = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['parola']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO utilizatori (nume_de_utilizator, email, parola) VALUES ('$nume_de_utilizator', '$email', '$parola')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
     printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($con));
else
{ echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);}


// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is the "autentificare", the database
[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DekAS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see the "online link"
eg: "http://localhost:8080/form.php"

 Do a simple `echo msg` - file to check and after replace 
`action="C:\xampp\htdocs\form.php"` with `action=http_link`

Comment: i've just tried this and now it's sending me to that link. so i guess maybe the database is the problem? or the php code? this is my first attempt.

Comment: link was the first issues after have to look on php file ...at first look seems fine, but have to go into details. Just echo out nume, email, pass and check them ... and mayble sql querry ...

Comment: what is `$link` inside $mail ???... just for the moment `$mail = $_REQUEST['email']` grab it as it is and check insert, after fine to refine

Comment: `https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp` - similar example using object, adapt it if needed ...

Comment: changed it and still nothing... i'm giving up. I also tried changing $_request with $_post.

Comment: too bad then, but maybe is check again the syntax ... seems faulty. Use `https://phpcodechecker.com/` and paste your php. On my side said : "Error: There is 1 more closing curly braces '}' found" ... so cannot work is php have errors

Comment: remove`}` from the end !

Comment: syntax is fine now, but what is the output ?

Comment: `echo $sql` before and rechecked ... if fine look again on connection (user,pass, etc)

Comment: same, after i hit submit, nothing happens

Comment: take it step by step. 1_put an echo at begin, 2_after_if, 3_sql, 4_on end ... see which you can see

Comment: if nothing maybe "http://localhost:8080/form.php" is not fine ... maybe port is 80 or/else , "http://localhost:8080" -> should goes to main page -> if fine then link is ok ...

Comment: "still nothing." ? after what ... put an echo on start ?

Comment: it's matter ... so that's means `submit` is  going to `http:\\localhost:8080\form.php` but there is no file ... so link is wrong. Maybe `http:\\localhost\form.php` or some other port 8181 ... do not know how was set up ..

Comment: `link was the first issues` - this is not yet solved ! just after look on php (if link fine first echo should trigger)

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED WITH: http:\\localhost\form.php <3

Comment: Very well then ... keep going !